# Saving captured image as PNG of JPEG

Tags: java, android, image

I am new to Android. I am using a camera application in Eclipse. The captured image is stored to **APPLICATION FOLDER(INTERNAL STORAGE)**. The image is stored as JPEG Format, but I want it to be save as PNG Format. However, I don't want to save the image on **EXTERNAL STORAGE DIRECTORY**.

Here is my code :

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyymmddhhmmss");
        String date = dateFormat.format(new Date());
        String photoFile = "Picture_" + date + ".JPEG";

        String filename = pictureFileDir.getPath() + File.separator + photoFile;
        File pictureFile = new File(filename);    


        try {
          FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(pictureFile);
          bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG,100,fos);

          fos.flush();
          // fos.write(data);
          fos.close();
          Toast.makeText(context, "New Image saved:" + photoFile,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } catch (Exception error) {
        //Log.d(IntersaActivity.DEBUG_TAG, "File" + filename + "not saved: "+ error.getMessage());
      Toast.makeText(context, "Image could not be saved.",
          Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
  }

  private File getDir() {
      String filepath = "MyFileStorage";
      ContextWrapper contextWrapper = new ContextWrapper(context);
        File sdDir = contextWrapper.getDir(filepath, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    //File sdDir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
    return new File(sdDir, "CameraAPIDemo");
  }
}
```

Comment: Instead of using the `.JPEG` extension just change it to `.PNG`  and your image will be saved as PNG. `String photoFile = "Picture_" + date + ".PNG";` Change this line.

Comment: @Luiggi Mendoza:Thanks for your response.Actually i changed that line Like ".PNG" .It will be stored in Internal storage as ".PNG" and when i opened that picture with Paint it shows JPEG Type Format only when i clicked the SaveAs button.(Normally some ".PNG" image open with paint means,it shows PNG Format when i clicked the SaveAs Button.)what is the solution for this. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Sorry but I haven't posted any kind of answer or advice here =\

Comment: That is the default Paint behavior  it always open the PNG image as JPEG.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
private void savePicture(String filename, Bitmap b, Context ctx){
    try {
        ObjectOutputStream oos;
        FileOutputStream out;// = new FileOutputStream(filename);
        out = ctx.openFileOutput(filename, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        oos = new ObjectOutputStream(out);
        b.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, oos);

        oos.close();
        oos.notifyAll();
        out.notifyAll();
        out.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

And set the extension of the file name to be PNG

Hope it helps.

EDIT: Your total code with calls to this method.

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyymmddhhmmss");
String date = dateFormat.format(new Date());
String photoFile = "Picture_" + date + ".PNG";

String filename = pictureFileDir.getPath() + File.separator + photoFile;   

try {
    savePicture(filename, bmp, context);
    Toast.makeText(context, "New Image saved:" + photoFile,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
} catch (Exception error) {
    Toast.makeText(context, "Image could not be saved.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Comment: @Grishu,@Luiggi Mendoza,@Sri Harsha Chilapati:Thanks for your Response.If i download the PNG image from browser and open with paint and click SaveAs button means,it shows PNG Format in SaveAs Type.But,If i download the captured image(.PNG) from Internal memory and open with paint,and click the SaveAs means it shows JPEG Format in SaveAs Type.Thats why?..Thanks in Advance.

Comment: :I have update the code above.It shows error(The local variable oos may not have been initialized).However i initialized null valued to the oos and captured the image,then it can't store the image in the APPLICATION FOLDER(INTERNAL STORAGE).Thanks in Advance.